# PresentViewController Custom Size & Centered in Xcode 5 and iOS 7

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have read through all of the solutions on here and still am having this issue.  I have tried almost anything that I can think of or find.

We just updated to using Xcode 5.0.2 from Xcode 4.6.3 and the code from 4.6.3 worked with no issue.  Currently my code looks like this.  This is what used to work and I have come back to this because nothing else has worked either.

At this point the size is correct but its in the upper right corner of the screen.

I've also tried adding

```
actionViewController.View.Center = this.View.Center;
```

but it didn't change the centre.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I'm going crazy at the moment :)

```
IStoryboard storyBoard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("WorkOrderActions_iPad", null);
        VZWOActionViewController actionViewController =     (VZWOActionViewController)storyBoard.InstantiateViewController ("VZWOActionViewController");

        actionViewController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet;
        actionViewController.actionViewControllerID = actionViewControllerName;


        this.PresentViewController (actionViewController, true, completionHandler: null);


        if (actionViewController.View.Superview != null) {
            actionViewController.View.Superview.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleMargins;
            actionViewController.View.Superview.Bounds = new RectangleF (0.0f,0.0f, 924.0f, 648.0f);

        }
```

Comment: This happens with page sheet, page sheet will not be center, form sheet is working fine, so you can use form sheet or you should move superview so view looks on center. this is work around for page sheet

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in iOS 7, this can be fix only if you set transition to cross dissolve.

`actionViewController.ModalTransitionStyle= UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDisolve`